# Is there a way to change the virtualenv interpreter when using create_environmen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv

I'm using python3.7 interpreter and I would like to create a python2.7 virtualenv using 'create_environment' method.

```py
import virtualenv
virtualenv.create_environment('venv')
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I would like to known if it's possible using create_environment virtualenv method. Not the command line tool.

Comment: Through the method, it doesn't look like it allows you to specify a version, the parameter you are passing in is the home_dir to where it is being saved. Would it be feasable to run a subprocess call or use os to run a command via cmd prompt?